# Filter 2-dim array based on string value that contain on 2nd array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, logic

so i have a bad bad logic for this assignment, i need to filter 2 Dimension Array that contains the value of string that input on 2nd array.

So this is the example of the 2-Dim Array

`const roles = [ ['roles', 'admin', 'write'] ['roles' ,'admin', 'read'] ['roles', 'member', 'read']]`

I need to filter the array that only containts 'member' and the result is like this

`const result = ['roles', 'member', 'read']`

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a simple answer by drinking a water and trying get my brain straight hahahaha

this is the answer

```
const result = roles.filter(
  (dt) => dt[1] === 'member'
);
```

Comment: You code will not work if you change the index of `member` in the array for example try your logic with 

`const roles = [ ['roles', 'admin', 'write'] ['roles' ,'admin', 'read'] ['roles', 'read','member', ]]`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const roles = [ ['roles', 'admin', 'write'], ['roles' ,'admin', 'read'] ,['roles', 'member', 'read']]
const answer = roles.find(arr => arr.some((e) => e === "member"));
console.log(answer)
```

If you want to return multiple arrays consisting the same string say "admin"
use filter inplace of find in the above code